# c++ Stacktrace on nvidia-jetson-nano arm64

Tags: c++, stack-trace, arm64, nvidia-jetson-nano

So we have are trying to use [backward-cpp](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp) for printing stacktraces in our c++ application. In particular we are using a signal handler for catching errors and printing them.
**Note**: Using [llibdw](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp#libdwarf-and-libelf) for detailed stacks

Works great on x86_64 but fails to print a complete stacktrace on arm64 nvidia-jetson-nano.

Running sample bracktrace_test on x86_64:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
$ uname --operating-system  --kernel-name --kernel-release --hardware-platform --processor
Linux 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ g++ -g -rdynamic backward.hpp backtrace_test.cpp -o backtrace_test -ldw
$ ./backtrace_test
```

[image: x86_64 stacktrace 2]

Running same sample bracktrace_test on nano arm64:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
$ uname --operating-system  --kernel-name --kernel-release --hardware-platform --processor
Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$  g++ -g -rdynamic -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables backward.hpp backtrace_test.cpp  -o backtrace_test -ldw

$ ./backtrace_test
```

[image: aarch64 stacktrace]

Code for the backtrace test:

```
#define BACKWARD_HAS_DW 1

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "backward.hpp"
backward::SignalHandling sh;


void myfunc(int ncalls)
{

   throw std::invalid_argument( "sample invalid exception");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   myfunc();
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Issue tracking: [issue](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/issues/48#issuecomment-547749802)